# C# concurrent requests strange timing reported

Tags: c#, http, request, async-await, stopwatch

I am working on a console application that sends multiple requests to an API and I am making use of async, tasks and await. I am using the Stopwatch to show the time spent for each request/task and I noticed that it starts very low (150 ms) and there is adding around ~100 ms for each next task. 
I think the tasks are running concurrently because the program completes 83 requests/tasks in 8 seconds and when I measure the get request with Chrome it showed around 200ms.

Do you know why the time is increasing as the tasks go? Is there something wrong with the measuring or with my code logic?
Isn't this suppose to be faster? From what I red, **WhenAll** should run the tasks concurrently and the overall completion time is the max task time from the list.

```
public async Task<List<CatalogEvent>> GetEventsAsync(int id)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        var request = GetRequest(msCatalogEndpoint);
        request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        List<CatalogEvent> events = new List<CatalogEvent>();
        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var catalog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CatalogEndpoint>(response.Content);
        if (!(catalog.catalogEvents is null))
        {
            foreach (var ev in catalog.catalogEvents)
            {
                CatalogEvent catalogEvent = ev.Value;
                catalogEvent.eventName = ev.Key.ToString();
                catalogEvent.titleId = id;
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                catalogEvent.date = dateTime.ToString();
                events.Add(catalogEvent);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Task for Id: {id} took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms and was managed by Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        return events;
    }
```

I am using RestSharp package to make the requests.
The main method is like this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this list has 83 ids which I am getting from a database
        List<int> ids = GetIds();

        async Task ProcessEvents()
        {
            IEnumerable<Task<List<CatalogEvent>>> techBriefEvents = ids.Select(id => GetEventsAsync(id));
            await Task.WhenAll(techBriefEvents);
        }

        Task.WhenAll(ProcessEvents());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is the output:

```
Task for TitleId: 142 took 164 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 16 took 349 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 10 took 634 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 215 took 650 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 114 took 826 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 214 took 843 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 56 took 983 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 212 took 1001 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 168 took 1141 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 21 took 1168 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 26 took 1309 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 30 took 1334 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 213 took 1462 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 24 took 1510 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 29 took 1619 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 23 took 1669 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 31 took 1779 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 14 took 1906 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 18 took 1943 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 20 took 2064 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 19 took 2110 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 175 took 2222 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 15 took 2275 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 102 took 2400 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 33 took 2464 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 135 took 2563 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 5 took 2632 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 137 took 2750 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 12 took 2796 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 41 took 2911 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 136 took 2998 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 43 took 3084 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 139 took 3159 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 51 took 3240 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 42 took 3322 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 39 took 3393 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 44 took 3502 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 122 took 3583 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 36 took 3697 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 95 took 3744 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 67 took 3871 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 229 took 3896 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 226 took 4034 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 108 took 4078 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 123 took 4213 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 143 took 4285 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 236 took 4364 ms and was managed by Thread: 8
Task for TitleId: 228 took 4466 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 232 took 4540 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 230 took 4641 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 149 took 4715 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 176 took 4793 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 208 took 4902 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 155 took 4946 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 61 took 5057 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 190 took 5097 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 93 took 5262 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 194 took 5280 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 156 took 5419 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 101 took 5440 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 193 took 5572 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 167 took 5598 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 197 took 5730 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 111 took 5755 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 216 took 5882 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 60 took 5930 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 9 took 6059 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 152 took 6085 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 169 took 6218 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 154 took 6264 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 7 took 6403 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 141 took 6506 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 58 took 6560 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 172 took 6670 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 11 took 6730 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 17 took 6846 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 55 took 6912 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 166 took 7020 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 140 took 7069 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 110 took 7177 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 90 took 7222 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 160 took 7352 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 97 took 7400 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 200 took 7503 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 153 took 7556 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 207 took 7654 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 161 took 7721 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 231 took 7810 ms and was managed by Thread: 5
Task for TitleId: 202 took 7873 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
Task for TitleId: 220 took 8068 ms and was managed by Thread: 6
```

Comment: You are awaiting inside GetEventsAsync. If you want them all concurrent then don't do that. Instead get the catalog events out of the tasks after WhenAll

Comment: I see, in this case I need the GetEventsAsync to return a Dictionary<int, IRestResponse> to do the deserialization and the object prepping after WhenAll.
Thanks, I will give it a try to see the timings.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am getting

    `Task for TitleId: 16 took 54 ms and was managed by Thread: 7`
    `Task for TitleId: 56 took 0 ms and was managed by Thread: 7`
    `Task for TitleId: 142 took 49 ms and was managed by Thread: 8`
    `Task for TitleId: 10 took 53 ms and was managed by Thread: 6`
    `Task for TitleId: 168 took 0 ms and was managed by Thread: 8`
    `Task for TitleId: 214 took 0 ms and was managed by Thread: 6`
    `etc.`

but as soon as I start processing the results I end up with the total 8 seconds, same as before, something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious misconception is that "and was managed by Thread:". Unless `ExecuteTaskAsync` is very badly implemented, [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

If the requests are being made to the same host, you might be running into [service point manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager) limitations.

Comment: 'Managed by' is indeed a poor choice of words, I only wanted to see that I am not in the Main thread.

I am doing requests on an API witch means I have the same host and after reading the documentation you provided **ServicePointManager** by default has **2** **DefaultConnectionLimit** and I was not aware of that.

I increased the number to 50 and now the time is 3 seconds for all 83 requests.

Thanks for mentioning the ServicePointManager as that limitation was the one that got me thinking the tasks are not really concurrent.

Comment: Someone, please accept this answer so others can know .NET connection limit.

Comment: @AndrewO you asked the question, so I believe you're the only one who can accept the answer. You should see a grey tick that you can click.